# Javascript API gets preperties of member methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Hello I'm creating a small api for a project at work, here is the code:

```
var VDSL = (function(){

    var defaults = {

        resolvePhoneNumberUrl: '/domain.com/test'   

    };

    return {

        Map: function(el, options) {

            el = (el.jquery) ? el.get(0) : el;


            this.mapSettings = {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(37.983716, 23.72931),
                zoom: 10
            };

            $.extend(this.mapSettings, options);

            this.M = new google.maps.Map(el, this.mapSettings);
            this.kmlParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: this.M});

            this.drawArea = function(data) {
                this.kmlParser.parseKmlString(data);
            };

            this.clearArea = function(i) {
                this.kmlParser.hideDocument(i);
                this.kmlParser.docs.splice(i, 1);
            };

            this.clearMap = function() {
                this.kmlParser.hideDocument();
                this.kmlParser.docs = null;
                this.kmlParser = null;
            };

            this.redrawArea = function(data) {  
                this.clearMap();
                this.drawArea(data);
            };          

            return this;
        },

        resolvePhoneNumber: function(phone, callback) {

            var request = $.ajax({
                url: defaults.resolvePhoneNumberUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 
                    phoneNumber : phone
                },
                dataType: 'text'
            });

            request.done(function( reply ) {
                console.log('success'); 
                if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
                    callback(reply);
                }
            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                console.error( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                console.dir(jqXHR);
            });

            request.always(function(){
                console.log('resolvePhoneNumber request completed.')
            });
        }

    };

})();
```

What I noticed and did not like is this I load the page on my browser and on my console I type VDSL which has 2 methods as it is supposed to have. `Map()` and `resolvePhoneNumber()`

However when I initialize a map after executing: `var x = VDSL.Map($('.vdsl-map'))`
I once again go to my console and type `VDSL.` and guess what now every property of the new Map() instance is also inside VDSL. example that shouldn't exist `VDSL.M` , `VDSL.kmlParser`. Those should only exist in the scope of x. What should I do in order to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are assigning the values/functions to `this` which refers to the current object, here `VDSL`.

To achieve this, you have to create a new object and assigning these values/functions to it.

To fix it quickly, I'd do that :

```
Map: function(el, options) {

        el = (el.jquery) ? el.get(0) : el;

        var myObj = {};

        myObj.mapSettings = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(37.983716, 23.72931),
            zoom: 10
        };

        $.extend(myObj.mapSettings, options);

        myObj.M = new google.maps.Map(el, this.mapSettings);
        myObj.kmlParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: this.M});

        myObj.drawArea = function(data) {
            this.kmlParser.parseKmlString(data);
        };

        myObj.clearArea = function(i) {
            this.kmlParser.hideDocument(i);
            this.kmlParser.docs.splice(i, 1);
        };

        [...]          

        return myObj;
    }
```

But consider using a constructor function such as :

```
function MyObj (el) {
    this.M = new google.maps.Map(el, this.mapSettings);
    this.kmlParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: this.M});
}
MyObj.prototype.drawArea = function(data) {
    this.kmlParser.parseKmlString(data);
}
[...]

// And instanciate it using new
var myObj = new MyObj(el);
```

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)